# Elasticsearch how to replace "terms" query?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

Using Elasticsearch before version 6 the following query returned hits based on similarity to the query. Now in ES 6+ this returns hit based on whether they match any part of the query, all with the same score. This change breaks the rest of the more complicated query (not shown).

How can I get hit scores that match the older ES 5- for the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "some_field_name": [
              "iPad Pro",
              "iPhone 8"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In ES 5 this returns hits scored higher for matching all terms and lower for matching less. In ES 6+ this returns hits with only scores = 1 and so they are ranked with no regards to how many matched terms there were.

For instance a hit that has both terms is ranked higher in ES 5:

```
"_score": 0.87546873, when 2 of 4 terms match
"_score": 0.60353506, when 2 of 5 terms match
"_score": 0.13353139, when 1 of 4 terms match
```

This is much like the desired "cosine" similarity that we need (understood that this is not precisely how scores are created).

What query will return the same scores as ES 5 does for above query. In other words, what is the ES 6 equivalent query?

Comment: How about breaking the terms filter into multiple term filter with same field? The term filter still seem to have scoring as there is a boost parameter. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: Also refer this term_set query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html

Comment: the "terms" score is always 1, you can boost it but you are boosting 1 -- pretty useless. This is why it boggles my mind that they changed this so fundamentally but OK, now we need to find the new way to query for more "similarity" based scores. Yes have looked at "terms_set" but don't understand how it work in the context of the way we used to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Just posting it as a draft suggestion since discussion in comments is getting longer and clumsy.**

**UPDATE: Just checked both the methods I suggested and both seem to give similar scoring. Please try these methods and see if the scores you get are of any relevance to you.**

I get that it doesn't work for terms but I suggested to replace it with either multiple "term" filter which also has a boost parameter or else replace it with "term_set" query and set required_matches param to "1" since we want the "or" behaviour.

1) Using terms_set query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms_set": {
            "some_field_name": {
             "terms" : ["iPad Pro", "iPhone 8"],
             "minimum_should_match_script": {
                "source": "1"
              } 

            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

2) Using multiple term filters instead of single terms filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "some_field_name": "iPad Pro"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "some_field_name": "iPhone 8"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you were using boost in terms, then you should apply same boost in each of term blocks.

Comment: #1 may be doing what I want, #2 ranks 2 matches of 5 equal to 2 matches of 4. So #2 ignores how much matches the query and only counts the number of matches. #1 may be the answer, I will need to test more.

Comment: Okay, glad that something might work for you. In my tests, both gave similar scoring. Need to dig more on how ES does scoring in these cases. Can you by any chance reveal your mapping or how your data is structured?

Comment: The field used is mapped to unanalyzed string tokens, any array of strings that need no stemming or other analysis, basically they are ids and not always human readable.

Comment: Okay, got it. I tested on a similar kind of data. Hopefully one of above methods work out for you or we can try with custom scoring later. Tell me if something works out for you or doesn't.

Comment: 1) it is very difficult to test 2) it is a guess, it would be great if Elastic had made a deprecation statement with an alternative blessed by them. IMO the only safe way to replace "terms" from 5.x is with something Elastic says will do the same work. I'm still looking for something documented as equivalent in some way. In lieu of that, eventually we'll figure out how to empirically see if ranking or scores are the same.